# Is "series opposed" a correct term for automotive charging of battery?

Tags: terminology, batteries

What is the definition of "series opposing circuit"?

Comment: If you only want to understand how the alternator charges the battery, then you could ignore other parts of the electrical system that "steal" some of the alternator's output. You could pretend that the alternator output is that much less than its actual output, and you could look at a simplified circuit diagram that only shows the alternator, the voltage regulator, the rectifier, and the battery. Looking at that simplified diagram, it would make sense to say that the rectified output of the alternator was "in series" with the battery.

Answer (score 1):

> I have heard some call this a series opposing circuit...

The only time any two components of a circuit are *truly* "in series" with each other is when the same current that flows through one must flow through the other. That's not the case for the alternator and the battery in a car because current from the alternator flows through other parts of the circuit besides just the battery,...

*BUT*

If you only want to understand how the alternator charges the battery, then you could ignore other parts of the electrical system that "steal" some of the alternator's output. You could pretend that the alternator output is that much less than its actual output, and you could look at a simplified circuit diagram that only shows the alternator, the voltage regulator, the rectifier, and the battery. Looking at that simplified diagram, it would make sense to say that the rectified output of the alternator was "in series" with the battery.

---

> I think the generator operates at high enough voltage differential to charge the battery in such a way that the two voltages oppose each other.

There aren't "two voltages." Really, the alternator/rectifier output is connected in *parallel* with the battery. "Parallel," by definition, means that the alternator/rectifier output and the battery voltage are forced to be equal.

Whenever the battery voltage is forced to be greater than a certain threshold, which varies with the state of charge of the battery,* current will flow through the battery in the "wrong" direction, and the current will charge the battery.** Whenever the voltage is forced to be less than that threshold, the battery will discharge, and current will flow in the "normal direction," supplying power to the external circuit. When the voltage is exactly at the threshold, there will be no current through the battery.

---

* the threshold is called the "open-circuit" voltage of the battery. It is the voltage you would measure across the battery's terminals at that moment if you disconnected it from everything else but a volt meter.

** It is possible to *overcharge* a battery: A high-enough voltage will continue to drive current through the battery even despite the fact that the battery already has a full charge. This will cause the battery to outgas hydrogen and oxygen. It will deplete the battery's electrolyte, and if the battery is a *sealed* (a.k.a., "maintainence free") battery, such as you find in most modern automobiles, it will shorten the battery life.  The car's voltage regulator is supposed to prevent the system voltage from ever going that high.

Answer (score 0):

When two 2-terminal devices, AB and CD are connected together, B to C and D to A, *with no other components* we have a 'ring' configuration. From a topological standpoint we could describe the components as being both in series and in parallel. And, indeed, if either device has an emf (or if both do) the current through both is the same and the pd across both ($V_{AB}=V_{DC}$) is the same.

Viewed as a series combination, the battery and charger are connected in opposition to each other: as we go round the ring the emfs are in opposition (though the charger''s emf is greater) but viewed as a parallel combination the emfs are in the same direction.

As it is the current *around* the ring that charges the battery, I'd consider the series viewpoint the more useful, but there's a case for saying that 'series' and 'parallel' are meaningless for two 2-terminal devices connected together!